# Finding odd number of occurences and alternating constructions using grep

Tags: regex, grep, alternate, brainfuck

I have to search in a file with 300 000 lines of [brainfuck](/questions/tagged/brainfuck) code with grep for several constructions.

#### First Question

I need to find codes like the first code below, i am looking for an alternating + - construction, the other characters are seen as delimiters, also +-+ or -+- is correct. We start searching after the ], like in the examples below

```
++[>++>+++>+<<<-]>++++++++.---.+.>.<------.+.>.>. ∈ γ, (correct, it is alternating)

++[>++>+++>+<<<-]>+++++.>++++++.>++.++++.-----.>. not ∈ γ (so incorrect +* is followed by +*)
```

#### Second Question

I need to find codes like the first code below, I am looking for an odd number of occurences of - between a consecutive pair of <> and an empty <> is seen as an even number so incorrect.

```
++[>++>+++>+<<<-]>+.>++++++++.<-.----.+++++++.>>. ∈ δ (correct, odd times - between <> )

++[>++>+++>+<<<-]>+++.>++++++.<<-.-.>>--.<---.>>. not ∈ δ (incorrect, even times - between <> )
```

**Note, only grep is allowed, we may not use a texteditor, which I did first.**

Answer (score 0):

I got this:

```
sed 's/.*]//' file | tr -d "><" | tr -s "+-" | tr -d "." | egrep "\+\+|\-\-"
```

That does this:

1. ignore everything before first closing square bracket
2. delete all `>` and `<` since your description accords them no significance
3. squeeze all `+` and `-` to single occurrence
4. delete all dots
5. looks for either `++` or `--` in what's left

Comment: that is indeed correct, but I may only use egrep. I had the same for this one, but it was incorrect because sed,tr,tr is also used besides egrep.

Answer (score 0):

For both regex, use egrep with Perl option if available.
And you can probably remove the `\r\n` from the classes if you expect a single line.

Question 1:

```
 #  \][^-+\]\r\n]*(?:[-]+[^-+\]\r\n]*)?[+]+[^-+\]\r\n]*[-]+(?:[^-+\r\n]*[+]+[^-+\]\r\n]*[-]*)*[^-+\]\r\n]*$

 \]                                 # ]

 [^-+\]\r\n]*                       # Not - + ] or newline

 (?: [-]+  [^-+\]\r\n]* )?          # Optional - .

 [+]+ [^-+\]\r\n]* [-]+             # Required + . -

 (?:
      [^-+\r\n]* 
      [+]+ [^-+\]\r\n]* [-]*        # Optional +
 )*

 [^-+\]\r\n]*                       # Not - + ] or newline
 $
```

Question 2:

```
 # ^(?![^\r\n]*<(?:[^-<>\r\n]*[-][^-<>\r\n]*[-])*[^-<>\r\n]*>)[^\r\n]*<[^-<>\r\n]*[-](?:[^-<>\r\n]*[-][^-<>\r\n]*[-])*[^-<>\r\n]*>

 ^ 
 (?!               # Not an even sequence
      [^\r\n]* 
      <      
      (?:
           [^-<>\r\n]* 
           [-] 
           [^-<>\r\n]* 
           [-] 
      )*
      [^-<>\r\n]* 
      >
 )

 [^\r\n]*     

 <                 # First odd sequence
 [^-<>\r\n]* 
 [-] 
 (?:
      [^-<>\r\n]* 
      [-] 
      [^-<>\r\n]* 
      [-] 
 )*
 [^-<>\r\n]* 
 >
```